Buscar palabras con 4 carácteres o menos y guardalas en una lista
Estoy aprendiendo programación en Python y una de las actividades que me encomendaron es crear una lista que se llame Cortas que contenga sólo las palabras con 4 caracteres o menos de esta lista
frutas = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi"] 

utilizando List Comprehension. Sé buscar por índice, pero no sé cómo buscar con caracteres específicos. Me podrían apoyar por favor.
Gracias.

¡Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto.

La solución utilizando List Comprehension sería:
frutas = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi"]
Cortas = [fruta for fruta in frutas if len(fruta) <= 4]
print(Cortas)

La salida sería:
['apple', 'kiwi']


La expresión [fruta for fruta in frutas if len(fruta) <= 4] crea una nueva lista Cortas.

fruta es una variable temporal que toma cada elemento de la lista frutas.

if len(fruta) <= 4 verifica si la longitud de la palabra fruta es menor o igual a 4 caracteres.

Si la condición es verdadera, la palabra fruta se agrega a la nueva lista Cortas.


Entonces, la List Comprehension crea Cortas con solo las palabras de frutas que tienen 4 caracteres o menos.
La función len(fruta) devuelve la longitud de la cadena fruta, lo que permite filtrar las palabras según su longitud.

por que sale apple??

¡apple tiene 5 letras!

como estas empezando a programar te dejo la versión larga:
frutas = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi"]
res = [] #creas una lista vacia
for item in frutas: #iteras en la lista de frutas
    if len(item) <= 4: #verificas el tamaño con la funcion len
        res.append(item) # si son menores o igual a 4 lo agregas a la lista

print(res)#imprimes la lista de resultado

el resultado es ['kiwi']
